# Fatal error after disabling ctools

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I was getting fatal error to do with ctools along the bottom of each page of my site. To try to fix the issue I logged in as admin, and disabled 3 ctools modules in my website:

- Custom Content panes
- Page manager
- Views content pane

This gave me an error page and my site is totally inaccessible or viewable. I turned them back on manually in the database, but now I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function page_manager_get_task() in /var/www/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/ctools/page_manager/plugins/tasks/page.inc on line 266

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: enable page manager module

Comment: can you share with us the error message you've got after disabling the 3 ctools modules from the admin section.

Comment: The issue has evolved. I've go the site back online but I think the root of this problem is I created a backup of the ctools folder called 'ctools BACKUP' and left it on the ftp space. I can log in as an admin but when I click on the 'modules' button I get this message: 
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ctools_export_ui_process() (previously declared in /var/www/mysite.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/ctools BACKUP/includes/export-ui.inc:13) in /var/www/mysite.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/ctools/includes/export-ui.inc on line 363

Comment: there is also a security update available for ctools from 7.x-1.2 to 7.x-1.3 which I haven't done yet.

Comment: you can't create a backup for a module in drupal directory because drupal checks every folder to see if it contain .module file. so move your backup to anther directory other than drupal's directory

Comment: I've done that, but now I get this error message when I load the website up in a browser. It's still looking for the Backup folder which I removed.  Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/mysite.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/ctools BACKUP/plugins/content_types/block/block.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php') in /var/www/mysite.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/ctools/includes/plugins.inc on line 475

Comment: make sure to clear drupal cache or truncate all cache tables in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really hard to figure out a solution for your issue without trying different options; but I hope the following instructions will help you.

1. Backup your current database
2. Open phpMyAdmin or any desirable MySQL administration tool.
3. Delete all **ctools** modules from `system` table or run this query

   `DELETE FROM system WHERE name LIKE '%ctool%'`
4. Drop **ctools** tables `ctools_css_cache`, `ctools_custom_content`, `ctools_object_cache` or run these queries

   `DROP TABLE ctools_css_cache`

   `DROP TABLE ctools_custom_content`

   `DROP TABLE ctools_object_cache`
5. truncate all cache tables (**cache** table and all tables with prefix **cache_**), example of truncate query

   `TRUNCATE TABLE cache`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. After deleting the ctools backup folder I then run the database update tool. Everything now seems to be working correctly. I will keep a copy of your instructions above as they may be helpful in future. Thanks for all your help with this issue - the nature of the internet makes it very easy for us to forget to say thanks to complete strangers who help out for free - so THANK YOU!!!

Comment: You are welcome! When you ran the database update; Drupal already cleared it cache. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem earlier today and this worked for me......

1. run update.php and update your drupal installation like so 
   http://www.example/update.php or localhost/update.php
2. follow the instructions and update all modules as needed

Hope this helps